# model does not exist in the current context in view after opening project in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My project was working in visual studio 2012 MVC4 i opened it in visual studio 2017 and i see under URL,model,View Bag,im getting error stating model does not exist,Url does not exist in the current context,
i dont know what im missing something which i have to add when i want to open project in visual studio 2017,in webconfig my mvc version :

```
 System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0
```

i changed it to 4 also but still the same errors,what could be the cause?am i missing a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to run the project, even though it's giving you errors? I had the same issue when I started using VS2017 with an older project. For some reason, it could not resolve the dependencies and restore packages was not working. However, I am now on VS2017 15.8.6, and a simple "Rebuild Solution" did the trick. Failing that, you can try some of the suggestions mentioned [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168918/false-type-or-namespace-name-x-cannot-be-found-war.html). Good luck, I hope it helps!

Comment: yes im able to run the project but i see these errors on all my views

Comment: Try Clean Solution and then Rebuild Solution. This solved the problem for me and, according to the thread in my answer, seemed to help most people.